# Can I leave the airport in Curaçao without a visa during a transit of less than 48 hours?

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, transit-visas, cur

I am an Indian passport holder.

I will travel on 15 November from India to Port of Spain, with transit in Amsterdam and Curaçao.  The transit time in Curaçao is 22 hours, so if I have a hotel booking, can I enter the country for one day without a visa?

Comment: Mushir: you have created two different accounts (https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/69585/mushir and https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/69588/user69588).  You can [merge](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) them.

Comment: I have made the question somewhat more specific because I found a page stating that travelers with a transit of less than 48 hours do not need a visa.  The page does not say whether such travelers may pass through immigration control, however: https://www.netherlandsandyou.nl/travel-and-residence/caribbean-visas/do-i-need-a-visa-for-the-caribbean-parts-of-the-kingdom

Answer (score 1):

If you have a valid multiple entry visa for USA, Canada or the Schengen countries you are good to go and don't need anything else.

Otherwise, you may be able to travel to Curacao based on the below information:

> **Requirements for travelling to the Caribbean parts of the Kingdom without a visa**
>
> If you want to travel to Aruba, Curaçao or the other Caribbean parts
>   of the Kingdom, you must meet certain requirements, even if you do not
>   need a visa. For instance, you can only stay for a limited amount of
>   time and you must have enough money to cover your stay.
>
> **Maximum length of stay**
>
> ***If you do not need a visa*** to travel to the Caribbean parts of the Kingdom, you can stay for a maximum of 90 days in a 180-day
>   period.
>
> **Entry requirements**
>
> If you want to travel to the Caribbean parts of the Kingdom, you must
>   meet certain requirements:
>
> - Your passport must not be more than 10 years old.
> - Your passport must be valid for the whole of your stay.
> - You must have proof that you can return to your country of departure,    or transit through another country. This could be a
>     passport,    residence permit or visa.
> - You can provide proof of the reason for your stay. For instance, a    hotel reservation or an invitation from family or friends.
> - You must have enough money to cover your stay and any other expenses.
> - You must have valid medical insurance or travel insurance that covers    medical expenses. The insurance must provide cover for at
>     least USD    15,000 in medical expenses and include hospital care,
>     emergency    treatment and repatriation (including in the event of
>     death).
> - You must not be considered a threat to public order, public health,    national security or international relations.
>
> Please note, even if you meet these requirements, the local
>   authorities may still decide to refuse you entry. Or they may decide
>   to allow you to enter for a shorter period than the maximum length of
>   stay.
>
> [SOURCE](https://www.netherlandsandyou.nl/travel-and-residence/caribbean-visas/requirements-for-travelling-to-the-caribbean-parts-of-the-kingdom-without-a-visa)

There is a condition to the above i.e. ***If you do not need a visa***. The requirements for that are listed as :

> **Do I need a visa for the Caribbean parts of the Kingdom?**
>
> **Travelling without a visa**
>
> You can travel to the Caribbean parts of the Kingdom (Aruba, Bonaire,
>   Curaçao, Saba, St Eustatius and St Maarten) without a visa in the
>   following instances.
>
> **You are transiting**
>
> You do not need a visa for the Caribbean parts of the Kingdom in the
>   following instances:
>
> **Airport transit**
>
> You are transiting through an airport in one of the Caribbean parts of
>   the Kingdom, hold an onward ticket and meet the following
>   requirements:
>
> Curaçao : Transit within 48 hours
>
> [SOURCE](https://www.netherlandsandyou.nl/travel-and-residence/caribbean-visas/do-i-need-a-visa-for-the-caribbean-parts-of-the-kingdom)

Furthermore at the end it is mentioned that if none of these conditions apply to you, then you need to apply for a short-stay visa. But the conditions do seem to apply to you. So it seems that you can go there provided you have a hotel booking, enough money and the medical insurance.

For more information you can contact their tourist board  +(5999) 434 8200 or  info@curacao.com

https://www.curacao.com/en/directory/corporate/contact-us/